# Regex to match alphabets with dot and dash(cannot be adjacent)

Tags: android, regex

I need help with regular expression for android. I need a expression which allows only alphabets with . and - which cannot come adjacent.
 for ex. 1. college.name
         2. college-name
         3. college.name-  etc..

this should be a mismatch ex: college.-name

I have used this `^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*$` but it doesnt work.please help.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!.*(?:\\.-|-\\.))[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*$
```

Add a lookahead for the same.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/lR1eC9/10

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
^((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)[.-]?)+$
```

you can see its [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/cE7pN7/1).

Comment: this also works.thanks. but vks gave me the answer first.sorry :)